# Select all in DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datagridview

Given `DataGridViewCell Cell = DataGridView.CurrentCell;`, how can I select all text in `Cell`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [BeginEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit.aspx) method to edit the CurrentCell and select its text:

```
// Update CurrentCell to the provided Cell
// Can be skipped if Cell is actually the CurrentCell
Cell.DataGridView.CurrentCell = Cell;

// Change the grid's CurrentCell to edit mode and select text
Cell.DataGridView.BeginEdit(true);
```